# Doxygen - nested namespace causes incorrect display where referenced via .tag file

Tags: namespaces, nested, doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.4. I see the following problem which did not happen with my previous Doxygen version - 1.7.1.2

I created two projects - TestProject1 and TestProject2

---

### TestProject1

Contains 1 header file XBO.h, as follows:

```
/*! \brief XBO is boring   */
namespace XBO {

 /*! \brief XBONestedNS is also boring
    */
  namespace XBONestedNS {
}
}
```

After running this file through doxygen, I get a tag file in the resulting documentation directory as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<tagfile>
  <compound kind="namespace">
    <name>XBO</name>
    <filename>namespaceXBO.html</filename>
    <namespace>XBO::XBONestedNS</namespace>
  </compound>
  <compound kind="namespace">
    <name>XBO::XBONestedNS</name>
    <filename>namespaceXBO_1_1XBONestedNS.html</filename>
  </compound>
  <compound kind="dir">
    <name>TestProject1</name>
    <path>/abc1/users/someuser/userbranch/project/src/library/TestProject1/</path>
    <filename>dir_a1513fb003dc8c1062e5770a29b83379.html</filename>
    <file>XBO.h</file>
  </compound>
</tagfile>
```

---

### TestProject2

Contains 1 header file, as follows

```
YBO.h
/*! \brief YBO is boring */
namespace YBO {
}
```

In the makefile.doxygen for TestProject2, the .tag file from TestProject1 is referenced, as follows:

```
@TAGFILES          = $(DOXY_OUTPUT)/../TestProject1/TestProject1.tag=../TestProject1
```

When the doxygen files for TestProject2 are created, the namespace XBO (from TestProject1) is erroneously contained in the namespace list for TestProject2.

In other words, when a project is referenced by another project and that project contains a nested namespace, the top level namespace of the first project (ie the namespace within which is nested a namespace) is displayed in the doxygen documentation of the second project.

Comment: I have a similar issue with @pages getting thrown together into the related page summary, allthough they are named differently. Using tagfiles to reference other projects. Can you try to add a LibraryC and see if it includes those namespaces as well? I only get one "extra" external page allthough i have multiple tagfile references. Could this be related to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699195, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692537 or https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693406?

Comment: Hi, I get the same problem if I add a LibraryC.

Comment: I don't believe it is connected with the bugs mentioned.

Comment: i opened a new bugreport https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705285 where i assume that namespaces are flawed in context of pages, maybe thats closer to your problem